# php - connect to udp server

Tags: php, udp

I am about to write a function which returns true or false. If the function is able to connect to the game server (doesn't need anything further, just to check if it's running) via UDP and a specific ip, it'll return true. If not, it'll return false. Unfortunately, I didn't find anything useful by searching the web.

Edit: For TCP, I'm using this and it's working like a charm.

```
function loginServer()
    {
            $ipAddr = "localhost";
            $port = 1234;
            $fp = fsockopen($ipAddr, $port, $errno, $errstr);
            if(!$fp)
            {
                    return false;
            }
            else 
            {
                    fclose($fp);
                    return true;
            }
    }
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "UDP connection" like TCP connection. You can send packets to server address even if it's not running and never know if they weren't received. If your server can answer to some kind of "Are you there?" messages, then try to send one and wait for the reply (for some time).